Azure Frontdoor is Overwriting XFF header
I am trying to set up an Azure Front Door before requests reach my api.
The flow I have imagined mydomain.com -> AFD -> fdsub.mydomain.com
If i call fdsub.mydomain.com directly, the XFF looks fine. However, when i go through AFD custom domain, the XFF header is overwritten (i see 2 MS data center ips) and the XFF header that was before the AFD is moved to X-Original-Forwarded-For.
In addition to this, when going through the front door, the x-azure-clientip seems to be set correctly as opposed to the XFF header.
According to the Microsoft documentation, AFD should only append to my XFF and not tinker by removing the original XFF header.
Any help would be deeply appreciated.

How are you saying the headers are not present? Can you share the logs or screenshot of the issue?

are you sure mydomain is directly accessing afd because I see you have mentioned two DC IPs in btween and is your afd classic or standard or premium?

I managed to figure out the issue.
The problem was before the AFD. My Nginx controller and ingress did not have the correct configuration set. Meaning my headers were not being forwarded at all from mydomain.com to AFD.
I have added: use-forwarded-headers: 'true' to my nginx controller configmap  and that seems to have resolved the problem.
Thanks to this previous post, i managed to get back on track.
Sorce IP with Azure Front Door and Ingress-nginx

Ahh , I see, the nginx part was not known since you didn't share those details. Good to know your issue got resolved

According to the MS documentation, Azure Front Door should only append to the XFF header and not remove the original XFF header as per this doc

It's possible that the XFF header is being overwritten due to a misconfiguration (2 MS data center ips). You may want to review your Azure Front Door configuration and ensure that it's set up correctly.
to set up Azure Front Door, configure it for your API, and ensure that the X-Forwarded-For header is properly appended rather than overwritten
You can create a backend API App service
az appservice plan create --name apiAppServicePlan --resource-group arkorg --sku B1 --is-linux
"


You now have an API service running on https://fdsub.azurewebsites.net.

You can then set up a storage account for storing the diagnostic logs

create an Azure Front Door instance that routes traffic to your backend API and configures custom rules for XFF headers.

Now that you've created the App Service, Azure Front Door, and a storage account for logs, enable Diagnostic Logs for Azure Front Door
az monitor diagnostic-settings create \
  --name afdDiagnostic \
  --resource "/subscriptions/abcd-efg-hijk-lmnop-qrstuvwxyz/resourceGroups/arkorg/providers/Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/arkoFrontDoor" \
  --logs '[{"category": "FrontdoorAccessLog", "enabled": true}]' \
  --metrics '[{"category": "AllMetrics", "enabled": true}]' \
  --storage-account "/subscriptions/abcd-efg-hijk-lmnop-qrstuvwxyz/resourceGroups/arkorg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/arkoafdlogs"


This will now capture access logs and metrics for Azure Front Door and stores the logs in the storage account (arkoafdlogs).
Now configure the rules engine to handle X-Forwarded-For Header
FYI, all these header modifications are only possible with Standard or Premium SKU
References:

Protocol support for HTTP headers in Azure Front Door
Secure traffic to Azure Front Door origins (front-door-classic)
Secure traffic to Azure Front Door origins (front-door-standard-premium)
Create AFD using Standard SKU


My AFD was configured fine... it was our own setup that stabbed us in the back.
See my reply above, we somehow managed to reply in the same minute.
